# Increase of execution time while using multithreaded FFTW

Tags: c, multithreading, mpi, fftw

I am new to FFTW library. I have successfully implemented 1D and 2D fft using FFTW library. I converted my 2D fft code into multithreaded 2D fft. But the results were completely opposite. Multithreaded 2D FFT code is taking longer time to run than serialized 2D FFT code. I am missing something somewhere. I followed all the instructions given in [FFTW documentation](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Usage-of-Multi_002dthreaded-FFTW.html#Usage-of-Multi_002dthreaded-FFTW) to parallelize the code.

This is my parallelized 2D FFT C program

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N 2000
#define M 2000
#define index(i, j) (j + i*M)

int i, j;

void get_input(fftw_complex *in) {
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        for(j=0;j<M;j++){
            in[index(i, j)][0] = sin(i + j); 
            in[index(i, j)][1] = sin(i * j);
        }
    }
}

void show_out(fftw_complex *out){
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        for(j=0;j<M;j++){
            printf("%lf %lf \n", out[index(i, j)][0], out[index(i, j)][1]);
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    clock_t start, end;
    double time_taken;
    start = clock();

    int a = fftw_init_threads();
    printf("%d\n", a);
    fftw_complex *in, *out;
    fftw_plan p;

    in = (fftw_complex *)fftw_malloc(N * M * sizeof(fftw_complex));
    out = (fftw_complex *)fftw_malloc(N * M * sizeof(fftw_complex));
    get_input(in);

    fftw_plan_with_nthreads(4);
    p = fftw_plan_dft_2d(N, M, in, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    fftw_execute(p);

    /*p = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, out, out, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(p);
    puts("In Real Domain");
    show_out(out);*/

    fftw_destroy_plan(p);

    fftw_free(in);
    fftw_free(out);
    fftw_cleanup_threads();

    end = clock();
    time_taken = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("%g \n", time_taken);

    return 0;
}
```

Can someone please help me in pointing out the mistake what I am doing?

Comment: How many (real - not hyperthreading) CPU cores do you actually have?

Comment: @twalberg it's four.

Comment: How long does a single thread run takes compared to 4? Have you tried running just 2 threads? The speed up vs. thread number will become a slow down for too many threads because of threading-associated overheads.

Comment: which MPI library and which OpenMP runtime (or compiler) are you using ?

Comment: @atru single thread program is taking 0.71s and 4 threaded program is taking 0.92s and I have tried running it with 2 threads it is also taking 0.71s same as single threaded.

Comment: That doesn't sound good - did you try @GillesGouaillardet solution? Especially the timing for steps 1-4.

Answer (score 0):

That kind of behavior is typical of incorrect binding.

Generally speaking, OpenMP threads should all be bound to cores of the same socket in order to avoid NUMA effect (which can make performance suboptimal or even worst).

Also, make sure MPI tasks are correctly bound (one task should be bound to several cores from the same sockets, and you should use one OpenMP thread per core).

Because of MPI, there is a risk your OpenMP threads end up doing time sharing.

At first, i recommend you start printing both MPI and OpenMP binding.

How to achieve that is dependent on both MPI library and OpenMP runtime. If you use Open MPI and Intel compilers, you can `KMP_AFFINITY=verbose mpirun --report-bindings --tag-output ...`

Then, as suggested earlier, i recommend you start easy and increase complexity

1. 1 MPI task and 1 OpenMP thread
2. 1 MPI task and x OpenMP threads (x is the number of cores on one socket)
3. x MPI tasks and 1 OpenMP thread per task
4. x MPI tasks and y OpenMP threads per task

hopefully, 2. will be faster than 1. and 4 will be faster than 3.